# Java Stack Overflow when reading Object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, stack, overflow

I'm trying to load an object into Java that I had saved from a program I had made.

When loading it in, Java threw a Stack Overflow Error.

The object I'm loading in had about a thousand entry object `ArrayList` inside of it, and in total ended up being around 128 Kb when exported.

I understand that a Stack Overflow happens when I make too many recursive calls, but I don't understand how loading in one array list of objects can cause this to happen?

I'm a self-taught programmer, so any insight would be appreciated that could help me better understand the problem.

Here's my code for the class I'm trying to load (Memboric)

```
    public class Memboric implements Serializable{

    /**
     *
     * The Memboric Core stores the various databases the AI needs to function.
     *
     * @author Brayden McKinney
     * @date 5/14/2013
     */

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4477889114653605232L;

    ArrayList<String> knownWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, Word> thesaurus = new HashMap<String, Word>();
    ArrayList<ConversationLog> conversations = new ArrayList<ConversationLog>();

    File location = null;

    public static Memboric load(File location){
            Memboric memboric;

            try{
                    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(location);
                    ObjectInputStream oo = new ObjectInputStream(file);
                    memboric = (Memboric) oo.readObject();
                    oo.close();
                    System.out.println("Memboric Core loaded and mounted successfully.");
                    return memboric;
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fn){
                    System.err.println("Failed to load Memboric Core.");
            }catch(InvalidClassException ic){
                    System.err.println("Memboric Core is incompatible.");
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.err.println("Creating new Memboric Core.");
            return new Memboric();
    }

    public boolean save(File location){
            this.location = location;

            try{
                    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(location);
                    ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
                    oo.writeObject(this);
                    oo.close();
                    System.out.println("Memboric Core saved successfully.");
                    return true;
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                    try{
                            if (location.createNewFile()) save(location);
                    }catch(IOException exx){
                            exx.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
    }
```

And it's sister class (Word) that it contains:

```
    public class Word implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 790247641945230263L;

    private String word;

    ArrayList<String> definitions = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Word> synonyms = new ArrayList<Word>();
    ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> links = new HashSet<String>();
    }
```

The error itself can be seen here (it's rather large):
http://pastebin.com/46bFZYVp

Also, the code above is cut down to save space (I removed the non-related parts) but the full classes can be seen here:

http://pastebin.com/tptmZ2LC
http://pastebin.com/3ickseFL

Comment: You could start by editing your post to include the stack trace (complete) and telling us which line in your code threw the exception.

Comment: One moment, I'll edit the post.

Comment: So what's inside that array? Don't you have circular references somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now. The object contains a list of words, and each word contains a reference to another word that it's a synonym with. I'll have to find a way to bypass this.

Comment: That shouldn't cause an issue - the `ObjectInputStream` caches new instances and then, for each new object, checks the cache. This means that circular references should be resolved from the cache and not result in a infinite loop.

Comment: And how would I go about that? (please excuse my ignorance on the subject)

Comment: Do you override the serialize mechanism in the Memboric class?

Comment: No, I simply extend Serializable. So do the Word objects.

Comment: Although, I load the object right before starting two threads. Could that cause any problems?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, having a circular reference will be handled by `ObjectInputStream` class for writing. But, the traversal of objects and through its references will cause `StackOverFlowError` definitely

Comment: Some how we have to avoid writing those references creating very deep nested traversal. For that, you can implement `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods so help your own serialization. If possible, pls post the `Memboric` class... Suggestion can be given more concretely...

Comment: Here is the Memboric Core class: http://pastebin.com/tptmZ2LC

Comment: Also, here is its sister class, Word, which is what the Memboric stores: http://pastebin.com/3ickseFL

Comment: @Brayden: Please post the code **here** on SO by updating your question...

Comment: You definitely have a circular reference or bad stopping condition somewhere. Since you only have 4 references per object, there is no way you are overflowing the stack without going into an infinite loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Move `synonyms` *outside of* `Word` and track it in Memboric or some other class:

```
class Memboric {

    private Map<String, Word> dictionary;
    private Map<Word, Set<Word>> thesaurus;

}
```

Basically, from a design standpoint, a Word can know about its own attributes but should not know how it relates to other words; each word is *independent*.  Some higher-level object can know about relationships between words.  This prevents cycles between object references.

**Edit**: The above works assuming Word implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly; if not or it's too much trouble, then use `Map<String, Set<String>>` for the thesaurus.